# Using Classes and methods with user input for an interactive program

Tags: ruby, class, oop, methods

Currently I've been working on a Lab project from the learn to program ruby by Chris Pine using the example where I should add the ability to fully interact with a tamogachi like program. I keep thinking that I can just define a variable for the pets name using `name = gets.chomp` and tag this on to `pet = Dragon.new name` but when I do this and execute the program it just goes through all the different methods for the pet and then wont accept input (I am using a while loop with options for the user).

**Lab Project Question**
*Write a program so that you can interact with your baby dragon. You should be able to enter commands like  `feed` and `walk`, and have those methods be called on your dragon. Of course, since what you are inputting are just strings, you will have to have some sort of method dispatch, where your program checks which string was entered, and then calls the appropriate method.*

```
 class Dragon

def initialize name

 @name = name
 @asleep = false
 @stuffInBelly     = 10  # He's full.
 @stuffInIntestine =  0  # He doesn't need to go.

 puts @name + ' is born.'
end

def feed
 puts 'You feed ' + @name + '.'
 @stuffInBelly = 10
 passageOfTime
end

def walk
 puts 'You walk ' + @name + '.'
 @stuffInIntestine = 0
 passageOfTime
end

def putToBed
 puts 'You put ' + @name + ' to bed.'
 @asleep = true
 3.times do
  if @asleep
    passageOfTime
  end
  if @asleep
    puts @name + ' snores, filling the room with smoke.'
  end
end
 if @asleep
   @asleep = false
   puts @name + ' wakes up slowly.'
 end
end

def toss
 puts 'You toss ' + @name + ' up into the air.'
 puts 'He giggles, which singes your eyebrows.'
 passageOfTime
end

def rock
 puts 'You rock ' + @name + ' gently.'
 @asleep = true
 puts 'He briefly dozes off...'
 passageOfTime
 if @asleep
   @asleep = false
   puts '...but wakes when you stop.'
 end
end

private

 # "private" means that the methods defined here are
 # methods internal to the object.  (You can feed
 # your dragon, but you can't ask him if he's hungry.)

def hungry?
 # Method names can end with "?".
 # Usually, we only do this if the method
 # returns true or false, like this:
 @stuffInBelly <= 2
end

def poopy?
 @stuffInIntestine >= 8
end

def passageOfTime
 if @stuffInBelly > 0
   # Move food from belly to intestine.
   @stuffInBelly     = @stuffInBelly     - 1
   @stuffInIntestine = @stuffInIntestine + 1
 else  # Our dragon is starving!
  if @asleep
    @asleep = false
    puts 'He wakes up suddenly!'
  end
  puts @name + ' is starving!  In desperation, he ate YOU!'
  exit  # This quits the program.
end

if @stuffInIntestine >= 10
  @stuffInIntestine = 0
  puts 'Whoops!  ' + @name + ' had an accident...'
end

if hungry?
  if @asleep
    @asleep = false
    puts 'He wakes up suddenly!'
  end
  puts @name + '\'s stomach grumbles...'
end

if poopy?
  if @asleep
    @asleep = false
    puts 'He wakes up suddenly!'
  end
  puts @name + ' does the potty dance...'
 end
end

end

name = gets.chomp
pet = Dragon.new name
usrin = ''
while usrin != 'exit'
 feed = pet.feed
 toss = pet.toss
 walk = pet.walk
 rock = pet.rock
 bed = pet.putToBed
 usrin = gets.chomp
end
```

(Alternate example gets the same output if only one of the methods is called from `usrin = gets.chomp`)

```
     name = gets.chomp
     pet = Dragon.new name
     usrin = ''
     feed = pet.feed
     toss = pet.toss
     walk = pet.walk
     rock = pet.rock
     bed = pet.putToBed

    while usrin != 'exit'
     usrin = gets.chomp
    end
```

If anyone can help me trouble shoot this so I can stop getting output like

```
name is born.
you feed name.
you toss name up into the air.
he giggles, which singes your eyebrows.
you walk name.
you rock name gently.
he briefly dozes off....
...but wakes when you stop.
you put name to bed.
name snores, filling the room with smoke.
name snores, filling the room with smoke.
name snores, filling the room with smoke.
name wakes up slowly.
```

It would be most appreciated since I'm still learning my first programming language this is a little frustrating.

The desired output for the program would be to have the the correct action taken on your pet when the user enters a command, like "feed", when prompted in the loop by `usrin = gets.chomp`.

Comment: well, you _do_ invoke all of the method inside of the loop. That's why they are called. Solution? Don't invoke them.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev unfortunately whether they are defined inside the loop or not defined at all the output at the bottom still prints when just one of the methods are called. I also didn't know that defining them as variables would print every method within the class, which is why I'm stumped as to whats wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you were trying to say, but you call all of the actions, unconditionally, at each loop iteration before you ask for user input. And the user input itself - it's ignored.

Comment: Same thing. All methods are called, input is ignored. What do you think should happen when you do, for example, `feed = pet.feed`?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add conditions for various method calls.

```
puts "Enter pet's name: "
usrin = gets.chomp
pet = Dragon.new usrin

while usrin != 'exit'

   pet.feed if usrin == 'feed'
   pet.toss if usrin == 'toss'
   pet.walk if usrin == 'walk'
   pet.rock  if usrin == 'rock'
   pet.putToBed  if usrin == 'bed'

   puts "What next? Choose one - feed,toss,walk,rock,putToBed"
   usrin = gets.chomp
end
```

Alternatively, you can simplify the loop by taking advantage of Ruby's [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send) as it lets you call a method if you know the method name.

```
puts "Enter pet's name: "
usrin = gets.chomp
pet = Dragon.new usrin

loop do
    puts "What next? Options:  feed, toss, walk, rock, putToBed or exit"
    usrin = gets.chomp

    break if usrin == "exit"

    pet.send(usrin) rescue puts "Invalid input"
end
```

Above solution will work only if you have a method matching the option text.

Comment: The pets name should not change for the duration of the program, this was intended.

Comment: Those local vars are useless, btw

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes they are

Comment: So what should be used then since I don't believe I'm understanding their proper use if I want to be able to input `feed` and have the pet be fed?

Comment: @TaylorSwanson I have provided a solution for your issue. Not sure what seems to be the confusion now

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning Ruby so I'm not familiar with `Object#send`. I just go do some more digging, thanks for the input @wandmaker and @sergiotulenstsev